# How to convert Logical Data Model into the Physical Data Model

Tags: mysql, database

I was planning to make a physical data model for my classified property site and I have only logical data model.I have not right methods that how I convert this into the physical data model.Please help me with details and if any book or link useful please provide me.![This is the demo image of my LDM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct method is to go back to your use cases and work how, and, how often the data will be accessed.

A reasonable 3NF physical data model derived directly from the logical model will perform reasonably well for most cases, but, perhaps not for your most important use case.

The most common physical model strategies are:---

- Make sure there is an index to support each SQL join.
- Where tables are always accessed together consider combining them. This is a trade-off easier, faster access versus painful and complex updating.
- Where you have a classic classification table e.g. (country code -> country name ) that is nearly always accessed with base table consider just putting the "country name" in the base table. (Again this is ease of access, speed of access vs. more complex updates tradeoff).
- If you are constantly computing sums, averages etc on your select statements, consider calculating these during values the insert/update process.

  But mostly its about studying your how your data will actually be used and identifying frequently used access paths.